# Display category image in product view gallery

Tags: magento2.3, product-images

I want to display the category image as product image.
So I put this code to my Observer:

```
$product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('catalog/category/test.png', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```

This doesn't work. But when I save the product:

```
$product->save();
```

He saves the images to the product permanently.
But I want to add the image only for this one request.

I tried also to manipulate the Gallery.php and XML, but then the zoom function isn't working anymore.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: Why you need to save category image  to product. You want to show at gallery section at frontend?

Comment: if you want to add images only  for one product pass the sku and load the product and then do your work

Comment: @Amit It should not save the image, but I dont know another way to add the image.

Comment: @mohith what do you mean with „do your work“. I have the product already loaded, but dont know how to add the image without save it permanently.